# DirectionsService not working as required by the code

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to make routes between any 2 locations I pass using DirectionsService of google maps. The locations are coming to me dynamically. But the problem I am facing is when the next 2 coordinates come it removes the previous route and displays the new route with the new coordinaates. I also can't use the waypoints because max. 8 waypoints are allowed and I need more than that.
here is my code:

```
var marker;
var map;
var mapOptions;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
function initialize() {

  var rendererOptions = {
    map : map,
    suppressMarkers : true
  }
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.53265,77.754812)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


}
//var image = 'C:\Users\Samir\Desktop\download.jpg';
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(23.32654,77.32685);

function Plot_Data(latlng){

    //end = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng ,
    map: map

    });

    var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:latlng,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

   start = latlng;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

A directionsRenderer will display only one route at a time.  This will add a new one for each time you call the Plot_Data function, but will still be subject to the API rate and query limits:

```
var marker;
var map;
var mapOptions;
var directionsDisplay = [];
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
function initialize() {

  var rendererOptions = {
    map : map,
    suppressMarkers : true
  }
  directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions));
  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.53265,77.754812)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
//var image = 'C:\Users\Samir\Desktop\download.jpg';
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(23.32654,77.32685);

function Plot_Data(latlng){

    //end = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng ,
    map: map

    });

    var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:latlng,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay[directionsDisplay.length-1].setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay[directionsDisplay.length-1].setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions));
    } else alert("directions request failed: " +status);
  });
   start = latlng;
}
```